# Android missing platform tools

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

Please can someone assist me with this, I have an Ubuntu server (terminal only), I have downloaded the android SDK, I have java installed, when in /tools I try to run ./android and I get an error Missing platform-tools. So how do I from terminal install the platform tools, for some reason I cant find this information anywhere.

Every resource I find assumes I have a GUI and not terminal, even ubuntu's page - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AndroidSDK

Comment: Why in the name of all that's holy would you subject yourself to this?  I predict that this will be the first problem in a long chain of misery.

Comment: Actually, its perfect now. Now my company has a nice front end to design and build their own android apps.

Comment: @Simon Would setting up a build server fit your need of 'in the name of all that's holy'?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Android manager has a graphical interface. But it can also be used via command line for some cases.

Run with `-u` (no UI) option:

```
android update sdk -u
```

Accept licenses (`y`) and this will install/update everything required automatically.

To update/install selective packages only, first list packages available for install/update:

```
android list sdk -u
```

This will list available packages with a number index, for Example:

```
Packages available for installation or update: 11
   1- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24
   2- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24
   3- Documentation for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
   4- SDK Platform Android N, API 24, revision 1
   5- GPU Debugging tools, revision 3.1
   6- GPU Debugging tools, revision 1.0.3
   7- Android Support Repository, revision 33
   8- Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator, revision 1.1
   9- Google Play services, revision 30
  10- Google Play APK Expansion library, revision 1
  11- Google Play Licensing Library, revision 1
```

Now you can install packages, filtering (`-t`) by number index to install only those:

```
android update sdk -u -t 1,2
```

---

On Linux: You can add android tools to `$PATH`:

Lets say sdk directory is `/home/user/sdk` then:

edit user's bash profile:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add following to it:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
```

and save (`CTRL+O` and then `CTRL+X`)

Logout and login again, run from terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

to verify.

Comment: Thank you, your a lifesaver