# How do I install Android platform-tools 18?

Tags: android

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916966/missing-sdk-platform-android-api-18), but when I open Android SDK Manager, I only see Android SDK Platform-tools, Revision 20 which is already installed.

I have also looked at [this queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511431/android-missing-platform-tools), but that did nothing because I already had revision 20.

Finally, I have looked at [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) which lists the platform-tools as a dependency but does not explain how to get a particular revision for them.

How might I obtain revision 18?

Comment: well it says

Dependencies:
Android SDK Platform-tools revision 19 or later.
So i guess you cannot install 18 as a dependency. anyway why would you like to install platform tools 18 since you already had revision 20?

Comment: @KostasMatrix, I want the android system images for android 18 and they are not available without platform tools 18.

Comment: Will this help? - http://htc-one.wonderhowto.com/how-to/get-android-platform-tools-without-installing-entire-android-sdk-0148147/