# Missing platform-tools when installing Android Studio on Mac OSx

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, ide

I am trying to install Android Studio on Mac OSx, with the goal of learning some Android development. The instructions provided were simply to:

```
1. Launch the .dmg file you downloaded.
2. Drag and drop Android Studio into the Applications folder.
3. Open Android Studio and follow the setup wizard to install any necessary SDK tools.
```

I get to the setup wizard, select everything, give it 6 gigs of ram when asked, then it proceeds to download components and install. However, at some point a popup appears:

`The following SDK component was not installed: platform-tools`

The output shows:

```
Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Installing Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1
    Installed Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1
  Installing Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 12
    Installed Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Google Inc. API 23, revision 12
    Updated ADB to support the USB devices declared in the SDK add-ons.
  Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
  Unable to run 'adb': Cannot run program "/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory.
  Starting ADB server failed (code -1).
  Done. 2 packages installed.
Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'
```

If I proceed to click "Finish" button, it opens up the Android Studio. But under ***Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK***, I see an error:

`Please specify a Android SDK Location`

There is [Standalone SDK Tools](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools), but I was under the impression that Android Studio would come with all packages needed to develop in Android:

`Note: If you have not yet downloaded the SDK tools, download them now. For a complete IDE and Android SDK package, we recommend downloading Android Studio.`

So I'm kinda lost on what things I should be installing. How can I get my Android Studio to 'work' on my Mac?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with linux

Comment: I am also having this issue. Seems like Android Studio's latest build has some issues.

Comment: The standalone tools for OSX do not include platform-tools either.  Quite annoying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, so I found a solution that works. This [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511431/android-missing-platform-tools) was using command-line to update the SDK. I went into my `tools/` and ran:

```
android update sdk -u
```

That pulled all the necessary SDK components from the server. Once it was done, I was able to point Android Studio to the standalone SDK folder and things seemingly work now.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I relaunched Android Studio after the SDK update finished and Android Studio continuned with installing the rest of the components.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem on Mac OS X. Here is how I fixed it. Open terminal and use the following commands.

```
$cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/

$./android update sdk --no-ui --filter 1
```

It will start the update of package in non-gui mode and ask for permission etc. and finally install well.

** I replied this on another thread as well. But I think this will help everybody because these are all related. I struggled much to find this solution. Depending on search keywords, people will end up in either of these threads.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar issue (Android studio 3.0).
Happened because I was behind a corporate proxy and the tools were not downloaded during setup.

Solution:

1. Configure proxy in settings -> HTTP proxy
2. Re-install Android Studio. proxy configuration will persist and the installation should succeed the second time (got additional window with the tools to download)

Answer (score 3):

The `android` command that many of the above answers use is now deprecated, and may or may not work for recent installations.

I just solved a similar problem to the above (for me the platform-tools package installed, but the installation was missing several files) by running the commands:

```
cd ~/Library/Android/sdk
tools/bin/sdkmanager --uninstall platform-tools
tools/bin/sdkmanager --install platform-tools
```

The uninstall step may not be necessary for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Android SDK (following by Android wizard), then add this path `/Users/your-user/Library/Android/sdk` in the setting under `Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK`

If not, please reinstall your Android Studio or download standalone Android SDK at link https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools and follow the above step. 
Default installation Android SDK on your MAC is `/Users/your-user/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: the folders under `/Users/your-user/Library` can only be accessed by `root` user or `wheel` group. Every time I setup Android Studio, the android sdk folder doesn't exist. I changed it to my local home directory, and it has installed the sdk there. However, I still get the `platform-tools` missing problem, and the IDE still can't find the android sdk.

Comment: you can try `chown -R <your_normal_user_name>:wheel your_SDK`

Comment: I already installed it to my local home where I have the necessary permissions, yet it doesn't recognize the sdk and is complaining about platform-tools not being found.

Comment: Can you run Android SDK Manager on your machine?

Comment: No, I can't. Nothing happens when I click `Launch Standalone SDK Manager`, and I also can't switch tabs to `SDK Tools`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. Check if you have this folder in your SDK directory:
[Android/sdk]/**platform-tools**

If not, you can grab it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209338/platform-tools.zip

Comment: Can you link an official download page rather than a dropbox link?

Comment: I downloaded the official Standalone SDK Tools, but I do not see [Android/sdk]/platform-tools when I unpacked the zip.

Comment: There's literally nothing preventing a malicious uploader to host a bitcoin miner like this, for example. Not saying you are one, just agreeing with @tempomax.