# How to Create Android TV Emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-tv

I just got emulator according to the following images:

[image]

And when I click Next, This window is displayed to me:

[image]

And there is no Emulator.

And Everything is updated in SDK Manager:
[image]

And this is my sdk platform:
[image]

How can I make an Android TV emulator?

Comment: run Android SDK Manager and download system image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the system image if not available.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have the latest (stable) version of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)
2. Make sure you have all the latest Platform and SDK tools (refer to my screenshots below)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then this is what my emulator setup looks like:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you uninstall and reinstall Android Studio? It looks like it's not getting the most recent versions of the SDK Platform Tools. Also check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919984/missing-platform-tools-when-installing-android-studio-on-mac-osx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313829/android-studio-cant-access-sdk-manager)