# How to set sdk path in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have installed Android Studio but i don't know how to set the `path of SDK`.

I have version new of Android studio but getting error in code.

> package not found import package dose not getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install it first time then do this as [@Ironman told here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38245858/5476209) and if you want to change exciting path from android studio then in your toolbar in android studio as shown in below picture,

[image]

you will see icon for sdk manager,this is icon for it

[image]

click it and you will see this prompt window

[image]

You can see Android SDK Location path on top of this window you can edit it as you want

Answer (score 2):

Download the SDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ to `C:\android-sdk\`.

Then when you launch Android Studio again, it will prompt you for the SDK path just point it to: `C:\android-sdk\`.

Comment: @user3627942 see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511431/android-missing-platform-tools

Comment: @user3627942 glad to help you.